# poll/epoll compatible Timer

Tags: linux, file, timer, epoll

Greetings,

I was wondering if there is a way to use a timer in combination with linux poll/epoll API.
I already use epoll and it would integrate very nice with the existing code if i could make the timer to be just another epoll event in my queue.

A possible way is maybe, a file-based Timer, like

```
echo 400;now > /dev/timer ; cat /dev/timer ; # outputs after 400ms "now"
```

just as an imaginary example.
Is there something like this? Or are there other ways i could integrate it with the epoll API?

--Marenz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is trivial to do timers with epoll, because epoll_wait also takes a timeout parameter; you simply put all your timers into a priority queue and set timeout to the time between now and the first one, then fire the events for that timer.

Or use use libevent which provides something similar.

Yes you COULD use timerfd() if you really wanted, but there's no need.

Comment: It’s not exactly the way I was hoping for, but it still works.
thanks.

--Marenz

Comment: actually, timer fd is exactly what I wanted. Too bad it's only for linux, though

Answer (score 0):

Would the `watch -n 0.4` command be any use in this situation?

Comment: I don’t think so. I mentioned the /dev/timer example, because /dev/timer could be opened using a filedescriptor and i manage file descriptors with epoll, so that way it would work, but not by executing another process.

--Marenz